# Nginx - redirecting non-www to www, but not subdomains

Tags: nginx, redirect, https, subdomain, regex

I have many domains linked to the same php directory, and I need all of them to redirect from non-www,non-https to www,https.

```
    # Add www, if missing
    server {
            server_name "~^(?!www\.).*";
            listen 80;
            listen 443 ssl;
            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/zipy_co_il_new.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/zipy_co_il_new.key;
            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.$host/$1 permanent;
    }

    # Redirect to https
    server {
            server_name "~^(www\.).*";
            listen 80;

            rewrite ^/(.*) https://$host/$1 permanent;
    }

    # Redirect to https
    server {
            server_name 144.76.173.84;
            listen 80;

            rewrite ^/(.*) https://$host/$1 permanent;
    }

    # Site description
    server {
            server_name "~^(www\.).*";
            listen 443 ssl;
            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/zipy_co_il_new.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/zipy_co_il_new.key;
            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            set $root_path /var/www/<path..>
```

This one works fine, but now I have to add a subdomain to my domanis and I don't want a subdomain to redirect to www, but yes to https, so I tryed to change the third line to(for m. subdomain)

```
server_name "~^(?!www\.)(?!m\.).*";
```

But it still redirecting m. to www.m.

Comment: can you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have a check that every request that does not start with `www` is redirected and gets an additional `www`. Because `m.example.org` does not start with a `www` it will be prefixed.

You could solve this multiple ways, but to remain consistent with your approach let's refine the regexp

```
server_name "~^([^.]*\.[^.]*)$";
```

So if the server name consists of two parts (i.e. naked domain), prefix it with `www`. If it uses a subdomain, then simply serve it as is. Unfortunately this will only work for simple domains such as .com or .org. But it will fail for something like .co.uk.

In this case we need to specify the actual top-level domains as part of the regex:

```
server_name "~^([^.]*\.(co\.uk|net|org|com))$";
```

This will move all naked domains to `www`. Subdomains will remain intact.